# Render condition error throws

Tags: apex, rendered, boolean, operators

I have below render condition that throws error. Can someone let me the correct condition? Please counter is a get set Integer value in controller that increments after a check in for loop inside controller.

rendered="{!IF(SelectedSize > 0 && (counter>=1) , true, false)}"

Answer (score 2):

Oh , I got my error. Corrected it as below.

rendered="{!IF(SelectedSize > 0 && (counter!=0) , true, false)}"